# Why does my bool function require "return true" to work normally?

Tags: c, cs50

I'm learning CS50x course. And the homework of problem set 2 is Caesar's algorithm.

I made it to work normally. But there's one thing make me confused:

the bool only_digits function - it requires a final return true to work normally. I searched on Google and people said there has to be a default return value, okay, I understand.

But when I switched it from TRUE to FALSE, the program just treated all the command-line arguments as FALSE. Therefore the program couldnt work.

I'm new to algorithm and programming. Please help me understand this part.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

bool only_digits(string s);
char rotate(char c, int n);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // Make sure program was run with just one command-line argument
    // Also make sure every character in argv[1] is a digit
    if (argc < 2 || argc >2 || only_digits(argv[1]) == false)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Convert argument to int
    int x = atoi(argv[1]);

    // Prompt the user
    string plaintext = get_string("plaintext: ");

    // Encrypt the plaintext
    printf("ciphertext: ");
    for (int i = 0, len = strlen(plaintext); i < len; i++)
    {
        char cipher = rotate(plaintext[i], x);
        printf("%c", cipher);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

    // Function check if only digit
bool only_digits(string s)
{
    for (int i = 0, len = strlen(s); i < len; i++)
    {
        if (isdigit(s[i]))
        {
            while(s[i] == '\0')
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
return true; /* This part, I dont understand why */
}

    // Function rotate
char rotate(char c, int n)
{
    if (isalpha(c))
    {
        if (isupper(c))
        {
            c = 'A' + (c - 'A' + n) % 26;
            return c;
        }
        else c = 'a' + ((c - 'a' + n) % 26);
        return c;
    }
    else return c;
}
```

Comment: The question is rather "Why is there a useless `while(s[i] == '\0') return true;` in that function? `:)` If you test whether a string has only digits, you can't be sure until you have seen all digits, hence the `return true` at the end. But if you see a non-digit, you know the characters can't be all digits, so you can return `false` early without having seen all characters.

Comment: `string  s` is not C. There is no string type in C.

Comment: E.g. you could wipe out half that loop body by simply saying `if (!isdigit(s[i]) return false;` . Maybe then the post-loop `return true;` would make more sense to you. The code `while(s[i] == '\0') return true;` is nonsense. The `for` loop iterates up to, but no including the terminator, so `while(s[i] == '\0')` will *never* be true, and thus that useless `return true;` thereafter will never be executed.

Comment: Without the `return true;` at the end what would happen if you called `only_digits("")`?

Comment: @Gerhard Yes, it is. In this case anyway. Blame Harvard's `cs50.h` header which aliases `char *` as `string` (and no, I'm not saying its a good idea, quite the contrary. I've long spoken out about what a dreadful "teaching" tool that library really is).

Comment: @WhozCraig then reminder about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) should be in order.

Comment: @MOehm I wrote that `while` loop to force it run to the end of string because I tested with a string `111a` before, it only checked the first char. But now to recall it I think I was wrong somewhere too so my code looked like that.

Comment: @WhozCraig yes, that makes more sense and finally I understand it. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I'll talk here about a single function, the one with the `return true` :

```
bool only_digits(string s)
{
    for (int i = 0, len = strlen(s); i < len; i++)
    {
        if (isdigit(s[i]))
        {
            while(s[i] == '\0')
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
return true; /* This part, I dont understand why */
}
```

So you ask `if (isdigit(s[i])` and then you start a while loop that terminates as soon as `s[i] != '\0'` which is already true as soon as you enter the if-body.

What you'd like to do is to check if there are any non-digits in your string.
Something like

```
bool only_digits(string s)
{
    for (int i = 0, len = strlen(s); i < len; i++)
    {
        if (!isdigit(s[i]))
           return false;
    }
    return true; /* if we didn't find a non-digit, we're fine */
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I wrote that `while` loop to force it run to the end of string because I tested with a string `111a` before, it only checked the first char. At first I didnt understand how bool works but thanks to your code I understood it.